# ZF2 2 modules with same name from different sources in vendor

Tags: php, module, zend-framework2, autoloader

I am working on a complex application that is divided in some sub-applications with their own logic. Those sub-applications are included in `composer.json` file of the main application and the module paths of sub-application are included in the main application.

For example main app `module_paths` contains:

```
./vendor,
./vendor/app1/module
./vendor/app2/module
```

The problem is that both `app1` and `app2` have a module with the same name and both of them need to be loaded in the main application.

Is there a way to load 2 modules with the same name but from different sources?

Comment: not possible to alias the offending module? `use \whatever\this as that;`

Comment: It's a best practise to always use a vendor prefix for module names to avoid exactly this situation. See here -> http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.module-manager.best-practices.html#utilize-a-vendor-prefix-for-module-names The ideal is to persuade the vendors to follow best practise and adopt a vendor prefix for their modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Crisp suggests the problem could best be solved [with a vendor prefix in the module name](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.module-manager.best-practices.html#utilize-a-vendor-prefix-for-module-names).

Instead of persuading the vendor and waiting for their next release you can easily [make a fork of the repository](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) on [GitHub](https://github.com/) and use your fork with the prefix in your application.

On how to include your custom fork into `composer.json` you can read [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs).

If you do this you can even make a pull-request which might encourage the vendors to merge your pre-fix solution into their branch.